# How to get the number of voice channels in a guild?

Tags: discord.js

I'm creating a "server info" command for my Discord bot: how can I display the number of voice channels?

Comment: Did you try anything to accomplish this so far ? If so, could you include the related code with some details so we can know more precisely where you are encountering some difficulties ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Retrieve a Collection of all the guild's channels with [`Guild.channels`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=channels).
- Use [`Collection.filter()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter) to retrieve a new Collection containing only voice channels.

  - *Compare [`GuildChannel.type`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=type) with `voice` in the predicate function.*
- Read the [`size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/size) property of the new Collection.

Consider this example:

```js
const voiceChannelCount = message.guild.channels.filter(c => c.type === 'voice').size;
```